# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigg((2\lambda)^{3n}\ \ln\big(\cos(n^{\lambda})\big)\bigg)$, for $\lambda\leqslant0, \lambda\in\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Study the convergence of the following series for $\lambda\leqslant0, \lambda\in\mathbb{R}$

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigg((2\lambda)^{3n}\ \ln\big(\!\cos(n^{\lambda})\big)\bigg)$$

I observed that if $-\frac{1}{2}\lt\lambda\lt0$ then $(2\lambda)^{3n}$ is the geometric series with ratio $-1\lt r \lt0$ that converges, whereas for $\lambda\lt -\frac{1}{2}$ we have $r\lt-1$ that diverges. In particular when $\lambda\lt -\frac{1}{2}$, the $(2\lambda)^{3n}$ is an oscillating series.

I am not sure how to handle $b_n=\ln\big(\!\cos(n^{\lambda})\big)$ which tend to $0$ for $n\mapsto\infty$. Giving $k=-\lambda\gt0$, can I say that $b_n= O\bigg(\frac{1}{n^k}\bigg)$ for $n \mapsto \infty$? Or am I wrong, having lost too much informations?

Comment: Saying that $b_n=O(\frac1{n^\lambda})$ - or even $b_n=O(\frac1{n^{2\lambda}})$, as in the answer below - isn't actually enough in and of itself, because $O()$ doesn't say anything about how _small_ a term can get.  Instead, for $\lambda\gt-1/2$, you need to bound $\ln(\cos(n^\lambda))$ *away* from zero, to show that it's not so small that it can 'counteract' the growth of $(2\lambda)^{3n}$.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki My aim was that of using the convergence/divergence of the harmonic series (maybe Leibnitz and Dirichlet when combined with an oscillating one). Do you find that this idea fails? What would you do? Thank you!

Comment: The problem with using the divergence of the geometric series for $\lambda\lt-1/2$ is that you have to show, not that $\ln(\cos(n^\lambda))$ is small enough, but that it's _large_ enough; in principle it's possible that, for instance, $\ln(\cos(n^\lambda))\lt n^{-n}$, in which case the presence of the geometrically-growing factor of $(2\lambda)^{3n}$ wouldn't be enough to guarantee divergence. This doesn't _actually_ happen, but you have to prove that it doesn't happen.

Comment: The idea of using the geometric series for comparative purposes is a good one, but you have to make sure that your bounds are correct. (Also, you should make sure to handle $\lambda=-1/2$ explicitly as well.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**. $\blacktriangleleft$ First determine the radius of convergence for
$$
\sum y^n \log(\cos (n^\lambda)).
$$
By **Cauchy-Hadamard** formula, we need to calculate the following:
\begin{align*}
\left| \log (\cos (n^\lambda)) \right|^{1/n} &= \exp \left( \frac 1n \log (- \log (\cos (n^\lambda)))\right) \\
&= \exp \left( \frac 1n \log (-\log (1 - n^{2\lambda}/2 + o(n^{2\lambda})))\right)\\
&= \exp \left( \frac 1n \log (n^{2\lambda} + o(n^{2\lambda}))\right).
\end{align*}
For sufficiently large $n$ we can assume that 
$$
\frac 12 n ^{2\lambda} \leqslant n^{2\lambda} + o(n^{2\lambda}) \leqslant \frac 32 n^{2\lambda}.
$$
Since
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to +\infty} \frac {\log (x^{2\lambda})} x &= \lim_{x \to+ \infty } \frac {2\lambda x^{2\lambda -1}/x^{2\lambda}} 1 [\mathsf{ L'hopital\ rules}] \\
&= \lim_{x\to +\infty } \frac {2\lambda} x \\
&= 0,
\end{align*}
we deduce that
$$
\lim_n \left| \log (\cos (n^\lambda)) \right|^{1/n} = 1.
$$
Therefore the power series converges when $|y| <1$, diverges when $|y|>1$.

Now return to the original question. Using the convergent radius, we know that the series **converges** when $|8\lambda^3| < 1$, i.e. $\boldsymbol \lambda \in (-\mathbf 1/\mathbf 2, \mathbf 0]$; **diverges** when $\boldsymbol \lambda < \mathbf{-1/2}$. When $\lambda = {-1/2}$, the series becomes
$$
\sum (-1)^n \log (\cos(n^{-1/2})) =\colon \sum (-1)^{n-1} a_n
$$
which is a Leibniz series:
$$
\frac 1{\sqrt n} > \frac 1{\sqrt {n+1}}  \implies a_n > a_{n+1} \searrow 0,
$$
hence it **converges**.

**Conclusion**: the series **diverges** when $\boldsymbol \lambda < -\mathbf{1/2}$, **converges** when $\boldsymbol \lambda \in [\mathbf{-1/2}, \mathbf 0]$. $\blacktriangleright$

Comment: This is very useful and complete, but we have never seen the convergent radius and the power series. I think it will be the first topic of the next course. Anyways, thank you for your answer!

Comment: @F.inc Or you could understand this as a practice of **Cauchy's root test**. Take the $n$th root for the whole term, then you could also deduce the same conclusion. Essentially [to this question], these methods agree.

Comment: @F.inc If you want to use Dirichlet test, your attempt is capable to use it to show the convergence when $0 >\lambda > -1/2$, since the log term monotonically tends to 0, and the rest part forms a convergent series, hence the partial sum is bounded.

Comment: @F.inc However for $\lambda < -1/2$, you would kind of be forced back to use root test to prove the divergence.

Answer (score 2):

> *I am not sure how to handle $b_n=\ln\left(\cos(n^{\lambda})\right)$ which tends to $0$ for $n\to\infty$. 
>   Giving $k=-\lambda\gt0$, can I say that $b_n= O\bigg(\frac{1}{n^k}\bigg)$ for $n \to \infty$?*

You rather have $\displaystyle b_n= O\bigg(\frac{1}{n^{2k}}\bigg)$. One may use Taylor series expansions to see this, noticing that, as $n \to \infty$,
$$
\cos \left(\frac1{n^k} \right)=1-\frac1{2n^{2k}}+o\bigg(\frac{1}{n^{2k}}\bigg)
$$$$
\ln \left(\cos \left(\frac1{n^k} \right)\right)=\ln\left(1-\frac1{2n^{2k}}+o\bigg(\frac{1}{n^{2k}}\bigg)\right)=-\frac1{2n^{2k}}+o\bigg(\frac{1}{n^{2k}}\bigg)=O\bigg(\frac{1}{n^{2k}}\bigg).
$$

Comment: Note that the last step in this chain is actually (partly) counterproductive for this problem - see my comment on the original post. On part of the interval, the estimate needs to be bounded _away_ from zero here, not towards it.